# Android added a plus sign before the number, making an undesired international call

Tags: calls, international-prefix

I cannot repeat this bug, but I can see it in my call log. Last Monday I called a friend with a number beginning with 328 (Wind provider, Italy). According to the log, I called a number starting with +328 which was an international call to Belgium, and in fact some people answered me in French.

I tried to repeat the bug, but without success. I only know that in some (rare) occasions the plus sign is automatically added to the call. This is causing me trouble because I don't want to pay for undesired international calls.

How can I avoid this? I know that I never manually dialed the number, I always choose it from my contact widget menu.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on your carrier?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to avoid this is to add your country's international prefix (It's +39 for Italy if I'm not mistaken.) This way your network providers treats it like it would without the prefix ie. it will be a domestic call if you're in the same country, but it will still work if you're calling from a different country.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could include the country code of Italy in all your contacts. This has the additional advantage that these numbers will still work the way they are supposed to even when you are roaming abroad. I'm not sure if either Android or the cellphone network handle this case intelligently.